# Apply scatter3 to each cell of a cell-array using cellfun

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, cell-array, scatter3d

How to apply `scatter3` on each `{3x10}` cell of `ycell`?

```
numOfSensors = 10;
numOfSets = 7;

%% sample data preparation
x = 1:3;
y = rand(length(x), numOfSets*numOfSensors);
yCell = mat2cell(y, 3, numOfSensors*ones(1,numOfSets)); % this is my sensor data

ycell = {3x10}    {3x10}    {3x10}    {3x10}    {3x10}    {3x10}    {3x10}
```

I have converted the matrix to a cell array. How do I use `scatter3` on each cell of this cell array?

Answer (score 0):

```
hold on;   %To retain the points of all cellfun iterations
view(3);   %To set the default 3D view
cellfun(@(k) scatter3(k(1,:),k(2,:),k(3,:)), yCell);%Applying scatter3 to each cell of yCell
```

[image: output]